# Can't load TGA image embedded with CMake?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opengl, cmake, embedded-resource

I'm trying to embed images and shaders in a single opengl executable file by adding this:

```
FUNCTION(ADD_RESOURCES out_var)
  SET(result)
  FOREACH(in_f ${ARGN})
    FILE(RELATIVE_PATH src_f ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${in_f})
    SET(out_f "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${in_f}.o")
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(OUTPUT ${out_f}
      COMMAND ld -r -b binary -o ${out_f} ${src_f}
      DEPENDS ${in_f}
      WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
      COMMENT "Building object ${out_f}"
      VERBATIM
      )
    LIST(APPEND result ${out_f})
  ENDFOREACH()
  SET(${out_var} "${result}" PARENT_SCOPE)
ENDFUNCTION()

ADD_RESOURCES(RES
    shaders/test.vert
    shaders/test.frag
    misc/a.tga
)
```

```cpp
extern const char _binary_shaders_test_vert_start, _binary_shaders_test_vert_end;
extern const char _binary_shaders_test_frag_start, _binary_shaders_test_frag_end;
extern const unsigned char _binary_misc_a_tga_start, _binary_misc_a_tga_end;
```

The problem is that loaded shaders work well, but tga can't be loaded. After looking into the log, I found that `&_binary_misc_a_tga_end`and`&_binary_misc_a_tga_start` did exist though the value of these address are all 0.

To make it clear, `&_binary_misc_a_tga_end`and`&_binary_misc_a_tga_start` are like those shader objects, nothing strange. The value from `_binary_misc_a_tga_end` to `_binary_misc_a_tga_start` are 0 which is strange.

misc/a.tga.o did exist. I also tried `nm` command whose result turned out to be

```
000000000092a212 D _binary_misc_a_tga_end
00000000000c0012 A _binary_misc_a_tga_size
000000000086a200 D _binary_misc_a_tga_start
00000000004d0c84 t _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_118tga_decompress_RLEEPhPKhS2_iii
```

Why this doesn't work on image file and is there any solution?

Comment: Are the symbols filled in in `misc/a.tga.o` ? Check with `nm`.

Comment: The best reliable way is just to generate a C source file. I guess `ld` generates position dependent code, so linker can't link multiple together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my problem has nothing to do with this embedding issue. The tga object was successfully loaded. It was the image loading library that didn't recognize the object due to my misunderstanding of the parameters.

So the conclusion is that both cmake and my loading code work well. Now should I just delete this question?

Sorry for asking this since I'm not very familiar with community rules.